# $y \prime=10^{x+y}$ how should I proceed from here?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

$$y \prime=10^{x+y}$$  $$\int10^{-y}dy=\int10^xdx$$ $$-\frac{10^{-y}}{\ln(10)}=\frac{10^{x}}{\ln(10)} + C$$ $$10^{-y}=-10^x -C\cdot \ln(10)$$

How I should get $y$ from here? And also, can I call $C\cdot \ln(10)$ just another constant $D$? Is that fine to do such a move like that? And if it is fine, what about if I have been given a boundary value problem?

Comment: Take logs of both sides to isolate $y$. $C\ln{(10)}$ is just an arbitrary constant as you say.

Comment: As result WA says https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%28x%29%27%3D10%5E%28x%2Bf%28x%29%29

Comment: @PeterForeman and what about the case I have boundary value problem? can I still write $C\ln{(10)}$ as an another constant?

Comment: @Sagigever Why would that be any different? $C\ln{(10)}$ can take any value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a separable equation, so we have:

$$\text{y}'\left(x\right)=\text{n}^{x+\text{y}\left(x\right)}\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\text{n}^{-\text{y}\left(x\right)}\cdot\text{y}'\left(x\right)=\text{n}^x\tag1$$

Now, integrate both sides with respect to $x$:

$$\int\text{n}^{-\text{y}\left(x\right)}\cdot\text{y}'\left(x\right)\space\text{d}x=\int\text{n}^x\space\text{d}x\tag2$$

These are pretty standard integrals, so we get:

$$-\frac{\text{n}^{-\text{y}\left(x\right)}}{\ln\left(\text{n}\right)}=\frac{\text{n}^x}{\ln\left(\text{n}\right)}+\text{C}\tag3$$

Solving for $\text{y}\left(x\right)$, gives:

$$\text{y}\left(x\right)=-\frac{\ln\left(-\text{n}^x-\ln\left(\text{n}\right)\text{C}\right)}{\ln\left(\text{n}\right)}\tag4$$

Now, we can set $\ln\left(\text{n}\right)\text{C}=\text{k}$:

$$\text{y}\left(x\right)=-\frac{\ln\left(\text{k}-\text{n}^x\right)}{\ln\left(\text{n}\right)}=-\log_{\text{n}}\left(\text{k}-\text{n}^x\right)\tag5$$

Comment: Thank you, in the last row you write $\ln\left(\text{n}\right)\text{C}=\text{k}$, can we do this trick even when I have boundary value problem?

Comment: @Sagigever You're welcome! Of course, you can do that, try it for yourself.